# Referrer-Policy header is always no-referrer-when-downgrade

Tags: python, django, referrer-policy

I have encountered an issue with setting `Referrer-Policy` header in Django.
I want it always be `same-origin` but it stays `no-referrer-when-downgrade` on the response anyway.

What I have done:

- started fresh django 3.0 project no MAC
- added `'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware'` to `MIDDLEWARE` django setting
- set `SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY = 'same-origin'` in django settings
- started dev server `python manage.py runserver`
- visited page `http://127.0.0.1:8000`

Actual result: `http://127.0.0.1:8000` returns `Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade` header

Expected result: `http://127.0.0.1:8000` returns `Referrer Policy: same-origin` header

Can someone explain me, why there is a wrong header?

Comment: Perhaps you are reading from the wrong settings? What do you `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` env var says?

(Btw, I know this is an old answer, so if you were able to figure out on your own, it would be nice to share what you did....)